# Как передать переменную в функцию ShellExecute()

Tags: c++, c, файловый-ввод-вывод, системное-программирование

Задача - получить имя входного файла и выходного. Скопировать данные с первого файла во второй.
Проблема - плохо понимаю синтаксис С++, не могу передать переменные в функцию.
Код:

```
cout << "Enter name original file: ";
string origFileName;
cin >> origFileName;


cout << "Enter name file to copy: ";
string copyFileName;
cin >> copyFileName;

//Как передать в строку имя входного файла и выходного ? 
ShellExecute(0, L"open", L"cmd.exe", L"/c \"copy /Y file1.txt file2.txt\"", 0, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Comment: Лучше отказаться от `ShellExecute` и взять `std::filesystem::copy`.

Comment: К сожелению, таск поставлен так :(

Comment: Возможно есть другой способ скопировать данные используя консольную команду copy, не используя ShellExecute ?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На основной вопрос:

```
string cmd = "/c copy " + origFileName + " " + copyFileName;
```

и использовать типа

```
ShellExecute(0, "open", "cmd.exe", cmd.c_str(), 0, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Только тут выбирайте - если работаете без UNICODE - то `string`, но без этих `L"...`, если с UNICODE - то `wstring` и соответственно читать из `wcin`.

Вопрос из комментария -

```
string cmd = "copy " + origFileName + " " + copyFileName;
system(cmd.c_str());
```

Comment: Аргумент типа "const char*" несовместим с параметром типа LPCWSTR. На "open", "cmd.exe", "cmd.c_str()". Как решить эту проблему  ?

Comment: А вы внимательно прочли ответ? *Только тут выбирайте - если работаете без UNICODE - то `string`, но без этих `L"...`, если с UNICODE - то `wstring` и соответственно читать из `wcin`.*